# CDN server blocked in corporate networks

Tags: cdn

My CDN server is getting blocked on certain corporate networks. I have added my CDN site to most corporate firewall directory to make sure its categorized correctly and not as a parked domain or other categories which are considered spam by web filtering softwares used by corporates. I guess the reason is that my CDN domain name is not the same as my websites domain name. Why I did this? Because I wanted to use a cookie-less domain for all my static stuff (images/css/js) like everyone else (twitter, youtube). Is there a place which lists all such directories where I can categorize my CDN domain? Is this the best way to do this? 
I guess the ROI of this optimization is pretty low and I might consider moving my CDN domain as a sub-domain of my website domain if I dont get any convincing answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting your assets in a separate domain is a common practice, even Server Fault does it (`sstatic.net`).  I doubt any of your hypotheses are correct, because they would cause problems with too many other legitimate sites.  I would contact some of the corporate networks that you're being blocked by (or have the users at those sites do it) and find out why you're being blocked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did check with one network where it was blocked. And the network admin told me my CDN domain was categorized as a parked domain in his web filtering software, which was the reason why it was being blocked. Also found that the other reason could be that the root (/) of such a domain should not serve any page and should rather throw 403.

Comment: So ask them how they determine a domain is parked, and fix that.

Comment: Yes I have done that already (in this case I needed to list my domain in their directory under the relevant category - the reason was that i needed to send 403 on the root of my webserver). However cant do that for all such software available in the market. So what I wanted to know was the set of rules which is like a super-set of all such rules used by all sch software.

Comment: There is no such list; proprietary block lists are always dreaming up new ways to screw their customers.  You'll just need to play whack-a-mole and fix things as you find out about them.

Comment: Yeah, I guess thats what I need to do. Worst case can make my CDN domain a sub-domain of the website domain. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Today SO did not work very nice anymore, cause my company proxy blocks cdn.sstatic.net where the CSS is located.
And yes it is a very big multi-million-dollar-company. So. This does happen :)

Answer (score 1):

The ip range for google app engine is being blocked by web trends. I don't think there is anything you can do if you are using google app engine besides setting up a small js script to detect if the CDN is being blocked, and in which case using your local resource files instead.

Comment: I think there is no other option but what you suggested. A javascript which could detect this and load from your alternate CDN.